# Firebase storage public URL "refresh" time

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have an image in storage with a fixed name, and this image can get updated by the user. The user then reads and re-reads the image from it's public address such as `https://storage.googleapis.com/storage-bucket/path/image.jpeg`

The issue I have now is that after updating the image, this url still shows the old image, even when open in browser. So even after the user updates the image, they still see the old one.

I'm on Android. When uploading the picture I'm using this metadata `StorageMetadata.Builder().setContentType("image/jpeg").setCacheControl("public, max-age=1").build()`. `max-age=1` is my attempt to disable this caching feature (I'm assuming is caching).

Is there something we can do fix this?

Comment: How are you re-reading the image? Are you using any Image loading or network libraries? If so, it could be that the caching is being done on the client-side by one of these libraries.

Comment: I'm using Coil library for Jetpack Compose. I'm also invalidating cache when needed. Still, when loading on a PC browser, the image is unchanged. Seems like a firestore cache feature. Never worked with something like that.

Comment: To be clear in case I wasn't - I updated the image, and the private url which requires a token showed the new image, but the public url which doesn't require a token (the one described in the post) was still displaying the old picture. I will test this again later today (this test was done on a web browser, not an Android app)